# Can I update my 4.0b iphone to 4.0.1, and not to 4.1?

Tags: iphone, jailbreak

I am looking for a way to update my iPhone 3Gs to 4.0.1, and not to 4.1 so that I can jailbreak.

Can anyone help?

EDIT - I have now tried, and failed on two seperate machnines  to restore from DFU mode to 4.0.1 The device is has 4 beta on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can view information on jailbreaking iOS devices at [Jailbreak Matrix](http://jailbreakmatrix.com/iPhone-iTouch-Jailbreak) and they include links to past firmware

Answer (score 1):

You can go to [this website](http://www.felixbruns.de/iPod/firmware/) and download the correct firmware file to your computer. From there, plug your iPhone into your computer and `shift-click` (Windows) or `option-click` (Mac) the "Restore" button. From there, choose the firmware file your downloaded.

Comment: Keep getting "the device isn't eligible for the requested build"

Comment: Hmm, perhaps this website doesn't have the correct firmware. Have you tried choosing "iPhone 4" under "Download iOS 4.0.1 via direct links here:"? If you have, have you tried the dropdown list? If you can somehow get the firmware elsewhere, the instructions will still apply. (Maybe try the link in Jon Erickson's answer?)